# How to show a description when a select box item has been selected

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

On my "node/add" form I have a "topic" taxonomy term field a user has to select. I would like to be able to display a description about a selected text next to the box, see red box in screenshot:

[image]

I'm sure there are CSS/javascript hacks out there, just wondering if there is a "Drupal way" for doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have the description stored alongside the taxonomy term as a field?

Comment: yeah, that would be a great place to store the text rather than hardcoding it

Comment: Cool, if you check my answer, it uses the default taxonomy term description field :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't strictly theming, but the following works for me:

Put the following in a custom module:

```
function tax_desc_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['termdescription/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Term description callback',
    'page callback' => 'tax_desc_get_description',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function tax_desc_get_description($tid) {

  if (!is_numeric($tid)) {
    return drupal_json_output('Select a term');
  }

  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

  $description = $term->description;

  return drupal_json_output($description);

}
```

This is simply a menu hook that calls a function.  You will be calling this menu link to get the description data for the taxonomy term.  The second function takes the term ID that will be passed in the ajax call, and gets the term object.  From that, it pulls the description set using the standard taxonomy term description.

Next, you'll need to add the following javascript and reference it in your module `.info` file:

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.taxdescGetDesc = {
    attach: function (context) {

      $(".page-node-add-article #edit-field-tags-und").after('<div id="mycontainer">Select a term</div>');

      $(".page-node-add-article #edit-field-tags #edit-field-tags-und").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/termdescription/" + $(this).val(),
          context: document.body,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (json){
            $('#mycontainer').html(json)
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

You'll probably want to change the ID's and classes that I've used, as I've just used a standard article type for this.

This Javascript will put a div with the ID of `mycontainer` below the select box (this can be styled/positioned with CSS so it matches your image).

when you click the select box, the term description will populate the div created earlier called `mycontainer`.

Just in case, your `.info` file will look like the following:

```
name = taxonomy description
description = taxonomy description from list

core = 7.x

scripts[] = tax_desc.js
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention, if this form is using the seven admin theme, you won't be able to put the CSS in your own theme file.  You'll probably want to include a CSS file in the module using `stylesheets[]` in your info file so it's applied regardless of theme :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery the `click()` event. Read more on http://api.jquery.com/click/.

```
jQuery("#idofselectbox").click(function() {
  jQuery("#idofreddiv").html('<h1>Hello All</h1>' + jQuery(this).val());
});
```